# Apply a middleware to this resource group

Tags: php, laravel

```
  Route::resources([
     'brands' => 'BrandController',
     'categories' => 'CategoryController',
     'products' => 'ProductController'
  ]);
```

Hi guys, I was looking for a while and I couldn't find if it is possible to add a middleware to the above set of resources.

Does anybody know if there is a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried grouping them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you can get this done.

1. **Grouping the routes.** Basically you group the resourced routes that has to pass through a specific middleware. Look at the example below. All of the routes are being grouped and passed through the auth middleware.

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
         Route::resource('brand', 'BrandController');
         Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
         Route::resource('product', 'productController');


   });
   ```
2. **Middleware on controller**: the above code will force all the functions to go through the middleware, But if you want to force middleware to specific function on a controller, you should consider putting middleware on the construct of the controller. Here is an example.

   ```
       public function __construct()
       {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
       }
   ```

If you do this, you dont need to define middleware in routes

3. linking middleware in resources route itself, here is an example

   ```
   Route::resource('brand', 'BrandController')->middleware(['auth']);
   ```

My choice is method number one as it groups similar routes in one place, makes the code little bit organized.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you! Perfectly explained!

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::middleware(...)->group(function () {
    Route::resources([
        'brands' => 'BrandController',
        'categories' => 'CategoryController',
        'products' => 'ProductController'
    ]);
});
```

Using a route group should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that simply like this

add this to route resource

```
->Middleware('your Middleware  name');
```